# export data from csv file containing unicode characters

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I would like to export data from a csv file which contains unicode strings.

Previously I tried a Python script which works fine for ASCII data only. But it won't support unicode stuff either:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import csv
csv.register_dialect('custom',delimiter=','
                     doublequote=True,
                     escapechar=None,
                     quotechar='"',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=False)
with open('input.csv') as ifile:
 data = csv.reader(ifile, dialect='custom')
 for record in data:
  for i, field in enumerate(record):
   print (" <field%s>" % i + field + "</field%s>" % i)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): for record in data: _csv.Error:
>   line contains NULL byte

Comment: post your code and error message / traceback

Comment: #! /usr/bin/env python

import csv
csv.register_dialect('custom',delimiter=',',               doublequote=True,escapechar=None,                       quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=False)
 with open('input.csv') as ifile:
    data = csv.reader(ifile, dialect='custom')    
    for record in data:
        for i, field in enumerate(record):
            print ("      <field%s>" % i + field + "</field%s>" % i)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    for record in data:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: There's no such thing as a Unicode file. Files are always in some encoding: this one is probably utf-8.

Comment: If the question is about Python 3; add [tag:python-3.x] tag to the question.

Answer (score 2):

use this unicode-csv library instead

https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

```
import unicodecsv as csv

with open('input.csv') as ifile:
  rows = [row for row in csv.reader(ifile, encoding='utf-8')]

print rows
```

Comment: I had never used Python , I download the package as specified by you.Can you please tell me how I can use the same in to my python script or what changes I have to do for the same to work upon Unicode based csv file.

Comment: there is problem in the file named __init__.py line no 49
except TypeError, e:
replace it with
except e:
am I correct or not? After this I am getting erro for     import unicodecsv as csv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python30\unicodecsv\__init__.py", line 3, in <mod
ule>
    from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name izip

Comment: I removed the import statment(from itertools import izip) from the file named __init__.py as python 3 wont need it anymore...
I am getting error as follows:-
    record = list(csv.reader(ifile, encoding='utf-8'))
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'UnicodeReader'

Comment: Can anybody help me in using the Unicodecsv-csv library......
I am getting the following errors:-
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 6, in <module>
    rows = list(csv.reader(ifile, encoding='utf-8'))
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'UnicodeReader'

Comment: modified ... I thought you could just call list on it ... but it looks like you need to manually iterate it

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `csv.reader` in a class to handle it for you. The following is taken from the  [csv documentation examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) and works for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import csv, codecs

class UTF8Recoder:
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self




csv.register_dialect('custom', delimiter=',',
                     doublequote=True,
                     escapechar=None,
                     quotechar='"',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=False)

with open('input.csv') as ifile:
 data = UnicodeReader(ifile, dialect='custom')
 for record in data:
  for i, field in enumerate(record):
   print (" <field%s>" % i + field + "</field%s>" % i)
```

There is also a `UnicodeWriter` class there if you need that functionality.

Comment: tell me how I can use it in my code as you can see my code above...
or send me complete sample code if possible....as I am beginner in Python

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me in soving my problem to export the data from a csv file which contain diffrent language strings inside ....

Comment: I've added a full code segment above, this works fine for me in Python 2.7.4 to read in files containing utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Python 3. Follow [the very first code example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='', encoding=encoding) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect="custom")
    for row in reader:
        print(", ".join(row))
```

where "custom" dialect is defined in the code in your question and `encoding` is the character encoding of your file such as "utf-16". [If you omit `encoding` argument; the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is used](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name escape

Comment: `html.escape()` is available since Python 3.2 . You could use `cgi.escape(field, quote=True)` on earlier versions. Note: it is unrelated to your Unicode issue

Comment: I am facing error because of line
from html import escape
How I can resolve it?

Comment: I've removed `html.escape` (to deal with one issue at a time)